# Main View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having problem with my `ViewControllers`. There are Four of them.
Here is the sequence of them. Sorry for the naming of my Views this is just an example.

---

```
startViewController ------> menuViewController ------> C1ViewController
                                          \
                                           \ ------> ImportantViewController
```

---

`startViewController` is my intro screen, after its finish, it will  `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];` into my `menuViewController`.

In my `menuViewController` are buttons for the two ViewController like the above illustration. Also I presented them in the View with this:  `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];` i return to `menuViewController` with this `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

What I wanted is to retain `ImportantViewController` to be the `MainViewController-like` even if I go to other Views. I dont know if it can be done in ViewController,but to be not removeFromSuperView or just put it Behind all of the other ViewControllers. Is it possible? And How?

Thanks.

Comment: Hold on a minute. So your question is "How can a child view controller return control to its parent?"?

Comment: I just want ImportantViewController to be there all the time.

Comment: No, more likely hidden. But keep its content live. something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your MenuViewController.h file, like so...

```
#import "ImportantViewController.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) ImportantViewController *importantViewController;
```

The key is making the property strong, which means your menuViewController will keep a reference to your importantViewController AND increment the retain count behind the scenes.

In your view did load (or anywhere, really), you can setup your ImportantViewController...

```
@syntheseize importantViewController;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.importantViewController = [[ImportantViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Then when you're ready to present it, do it like so:

```
[self presentViewController:importantViewController Animated:YES];
```

Then when you eventually dismiss it, your menuViewController will still have a reference to it and it will not be deallocated.  You can then show the same controller again later.

Note:  This is all assuming you are using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

Comment: How to reload the data that was retained like refresh type?

Answer (score 0):

Have importantViewController be the starting view controller, and present all of the other views modally. When you want to switch views, call the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated method and then present a new one. This will work if you have textfields or something that you want to be able to keep the information entered in them without saving/loading it every time you show the view.

```
//Inside all view controllers aside from the important one

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To show a new controller, either make a modal segue to it and call it from important view controller or programmatically call it.